# DBName must be null for engine error at AWS - RDS

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, rds

I am trying to create an SQL Server database under the free trial package on AWS.

I am completing all of the steps and once I press create database I get the following error:

[image]

I tried a number of things: changing the name of the instance, the security parameters, searching for possible solutions, etc.

Any ideas where the error is pointing to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution.

The error is rather non-descriptive. The issue was that the free-tiar of the AWS program does not support the latest 2018/9 version of SQL Server Database. But it works perfectly well with the 2014 version.

I'm posting this answer for a reference, as I lost some time on this.

Comment: The actual problem is with the html form and using my answer will get around the error and allow you to create a database with the latest SQL Server.

Comment: It works perfectly well with the 2016 version for me.

Answer (score 3):

Ref: [AWS Doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html) under "DBName" it says:

**SQL Server** --> Not applicable. Must be null.

Comment: I still dont know what that means. What am I supposed to change in the settings?

Comment: @Prometheus it means that you need to supply a null DbName - ie it doesn't need a database name when you are creating and SQL Server on RDS.

Answer (score 2):

**Try switching browsers and platforms. I encountered this error on Chromium/Debian, my coworker did not have this issue on Chrome/Windows10**

If that does not work:

1. Open the developer Console (Chrome F12)
2. Select the 'Elements' Tab
3. Use CTRL+F to search inside of Elements tab
4. Search for 'Database name'
5. Edit the form field element you find by removing **style="display: none;"** :

```html
<awsui-form-field initialized="true" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><div class="awsui-form-field"><label class="awsui-form-field-label" for="awsui-input-11" awsui-form-field-region="label"><div class="util-d-f"><span class="gwt-InlineLabel awsui-util-mr-m">Database name</span> <a class="gwt-Anchor GK15FVNCBQF" style="">Info</a></div></label><div class="awsui-grid awsui-form-field-controls"><div class="awsui-row"><div class="awsui-form-field-control col-xxxs-12 col-xs-9" awsui-form-field-region="control"><awsui-input initialized="true" id="rds-launch-wizard-db-name-txtbx"><span><input autocomplete="off" class="awsui-input awsui-input-type-text" type="text" id="awsui-input-11" placeholder="dbname" aria-describedby="awsui-input-11-hints" value="NULL"></span></awsui-input></div></div></div><div class="awsui-form-field-hints"><div id="awsui-input-11-hints" class="awsui-form-field-hint" awsui-form-field-region="hintText">If you do not specify a database name, Amazon RDS does not create a database.</div></div></div></awsui-form-field>
```

Now under the Database Options there will be a field for the **Database name**:
[image]

Remove the text in that field and submit.

Comment: I was brought to my attention that this problem was somehow localized to my machine, so an easier approach might be to try different browsers and platforms.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue,
**InvalidParameterValue: DBName must be null for engine: sqlserver-ex**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyB8d.png)

Please set the name parameter as follows:

name=""

(not name=null)

Regards,
Shlomi